# I am trying to call web API from controller, but @WebResponse response line is showing an error

Tags: c#, web-services

I'm getting an error and I could really use some help!

The remote server returned an error: (403) Forbidden.

Description: An unhandled exception occurred during the execution of the current web request. Please review the stack trace for more information about the error and where it originated in the code.

Exception Details: System.Net.WebException: The remote server returned an error: (403) Forbidden.

```
namespace mvc_web_api.Controllers
{
    public class HomeController : Controller
    {


        public ActionResult  Index()
        {

            string url = "xyz@xy.z";
            WebRequest request = WebRequest.Create(url);
            request.Method = WebRequestMethods.Http.Get;
            NetworkCredential networkCredential = new NetworkCredential(logon, password); // logon in format "domain\username"
            CredentialCache myCredentialCache = new CredentialCache {{new Uri(url), "Basic", networkCredential}};
            request.PreAuthenticate = true;
            request.Credentials = myCredentialCache;
            using (WebResponse response = request.GetResponse())
             {
                Console.WriteLine(((HttpWebResponse)response).StatusDescription);

                    using (Stream dataStream = response.GetResponseStream())
                    {
                      using (StreamReader reader = new StreamReader(dataStream))
                        {
                            string responseFromServer = reader.ReadToEnd();
                            Console.WriteLine(responseFromServer);
                        }
                    }
           }

        return View();
}
```

Comment: Guessing there's an issue with your login credentials. Hard to debug from the question.